Unable to mock awsglue module via tox
I have one method in one of the modules like below:
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from functools import *

class FetchArguments:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def fetch_arguments(self, args):  

and now for this class, I have written a unit test where I am trying to mock the awsglue library using unittest library. I have used a patch decorator.
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from utils.fetch_arguments import FetchArguments

class TestFetchArguments(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("utils.fetch_arguments.awsglue.utils.getResolvedOptions")
    def test_fetch_arguments_with_fullload(self, mock_get_resolved_options):

now when I try to run it via tox, it throws the below error:
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsglue'

Code is working fine, as I have tested it using the below first approach.
Alternative-1:
To resolve this error, I installed  git+https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs.git (latest glue library) and copied the libraries in the tox->python->lib->site-packages folder and my tests ran fine. But this is not suitable for the CI/CD purposes.
Alternative-2:
I directly tried running the test via this command too python -m unittest discover -v  but then it throws an error w.r.t python modules imported like the below one:
from models.model import SparkJobFactoryDetails
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'   

Alternative-3:
I also tried to put this git+https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs.git in my setup.py and then tried to install this package at runtime but somehow it doesn't accept this format in my setup.py file.
So given these scenarios what exactly can be done to make it smoother?

I know I can use aws-glue docker image but I was wondering if I could do it directly via tox. Also, I was able to solve it via Alternative-2 later on.
